# How to read header from .olk14Message file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, outlook

I have a `.olk14Message` file created by Outlook 2011 for Mac; contains the email's header information, but does not contain the email body contents, which are stored in a separate `.OLK14MsgSource` file. I want to programmatically read the header information from `.olk14Message` file so that I can read appropriate `.olk14MsgSource` file and its content.

So anyone know how to parse the `.olk14Message` file in `cocoa` or how outlook links between `.olk14message` and `.olk14MsgSource` files?

Comment: share olk14Message and olk14MsgSource sample file.

Comment: It's been a couple of years. Did you figure it out?